# Is there a python module that will give an estimate of remaining time for a long running process?

Tags: python

I have a long running process that is mostly IO bound. It is basically just a loop uploading items somewhere, some of these items take more time than others, some days the whole process is slower so the time can't be hardcoded.

Is there a module that given the progress through the loop in terms of (current position, final position) could evaluate the first few iterations then give an estimate of the remaining time, but also update on every iteration?

I'm thinking something like the progress output you get from tools like wget and apt-get.

I guess I could write it myself but I wondered if something like this exists already.

Comment: Have you seen this by any chance? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2

Comment: Thanks, I think that might be what I'm looking for